# Finding the index of an element in a list

Tags: haskell, indexof

I'm a beginner in Haskell and I've been having trouble with my practice programs. For this particular one, I want to find the index of an element in a list (the first element being at 0). 
If the element given does not appear in the list, I am having the program return -1.

Here is my code:

```
indexOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
indexOf n [] = (-1)
indexOf n (x:xs)
    | n == x    = length(xs)
    | otherwise = n `indexOf` xs
```

I have experience in both C and Java, so my gut instinct is to get a counter to increment every time I go through the list, but, I keep reminding myself that isn't how Haskell works. 
I'm aware that my code is shifting the head of the list every time it goes through and when I do "length(xs)", it is merely finding the length of the remainder of the list.
Clearly, I'm very stumped here. Can anyone offer any pointers or recommendations on how I can get this piece of code to work?

Comment: For non-total functions, it is common to return a `Maybe`, so a `Maybe Int`, where we return a `Nothing` if an element is not found, or `Just i` when it found an item on index `i`.

Answer (score 7):

The way I'd solve it is create another recursive function with the same singature plus additional `Int` parameter to work as accumulator:

```
indexOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
indexOf n xs = go 0 n xs
    where
        go i n [] = (-1)
        go i n (x:xs)
             | n == x    = i
             | otherwise = go (i+1) n xs
```

Comment: Note we can omit the `n` argument in `go`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a counter (increment as you go down the list) you can also modify the return value as you go back up again:

```
indexOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
indexOf n [] = -1
indexOf n (x:xs)
    | n == x    = 0
    | otherwise = case n `indexOf` xs of
        -1 -> -1
        i  -> i + 1
```

Answer (score 5):

This function is already present in the library ([`elemIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex)), but let's implement it anyway.

Given `xs = [x0,x1,...]`, we have `zip xs [0..] = [(x0,0),(x1,1),...]`. We can then search on the latter list for a pair satisfying the predicate `\(x,_) -> x==n`.

```
import Data.List

indexOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
indexOf n xs = fmap snd . find (\(x,_) -> x==n) $ zip xs [0..]
```

Above, `zip` adds indices, `find` will return `Just (n,index)` on success, and the `fmap snd` transforms that into `Just index`.

Note how we prefer to return `Nothing` instead of `-1`, which is not idiomatic in Haskell, where we prefer using `Maybe` instead.

Finally, note that the above code is not inefficient: thanks to laziness, `zip` will only add the indices to those elements which are demanded by `find`, so it will not scan the whole list unless the wanted element is not found.

As an exercise, you might want to code `fmap snd . find (\(x,_) -> x==n)` with explicit recursion.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, one usually uses a `Maybe a` to return a value `a`, but when not all input per se is valid. For invalid input, we return `Nothing`, for valid, we return `Just x` with `x` the result.

We thus can implement the `indexOf` where we map the empty list on `Nothing`. In case the first item of the list is equal to the item we are looking for, we return `Just 0`. In case the first item is not equal to the item we are looking for, we recurse on the tail of the list, and increment the value wrapped in the `Just`, given there is such value:

```
indexOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
indexOf y = go
    where go [] = Nothing
          go (x:xs) | x == y = Just 0
                    | otherwise = (1+) <$> go xs
```